# Video larger than screen size in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, ipad

There is this website which is adapted to iPad, it has videos that can play directly in Chrome, but the video player is larger than my screen size, I have to scroll up and down. Is there any workarounds that I could do to show the videos in their original size? The video is usually 640x480.

It is an ... adult website. http://ipad.madthumbs.com/

Comment: What kind of  video player is that? Can you give us the link to this website?

Comment: @yanglifu: It seems that you might have accessed the direct embedded video url.